# Woocommerce Storefront navigation menu color change for active product category page & Cart menu item

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I have changed the primary-navigation-menu current page color by below CSS

```
.current_page_item a {
    color: #4fff51!important; }
```

But it is working for only pages, **not for product category pages & Cart menu item**

In the menu, **Home** & **Shop** are the pages and remaining are the product category pages.

This is my website [graceamaron.com](https://graceamaron.com/)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the product pages are children of `Store` the store list item is not seen as the current page, so you will have to add an extra class to select by parent. You do this by adding `.current_page_parent a` to the CSS.

After looking a bit further through your site, I also saw the following link still shows up gray: https://graceamaron.com/product-category/homeups/

if you add `.current-menu-item a` to the CSS, it will also change the color for this nav item.

To make your cart green as well when selected, add `.site-header-cart .current-menu-item a` to the class.

To solve these issues, change your class to the following:

```
.site-header-cart .current-menu-item a,
.main-navigation .current_page_parent a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-item a,
.main-navigation .current_page_item a {
    color : #4fff51!important;
}
```

Previews of the class working:

Product Page:
[image]

Category Page:
[image]

Comment: yes, it's working fuziion, but I want this only for primary navigation menu and not for secondary menu. by your above CSS it's working for both. See my site now.

Comment: Where is the secondary menu? I can't see it

Comment: beside the search bar

Comment: So you don't want those to be green when active correct?

Comment: yes fuziion, right

Comment: updated the answer, adding `.main-navigation` infront of the selectors will force them to only look into the main nav menu

Comment: ok it's working now..
But one more thing it's not being green when cart menu active ..
pls look unto this one too ..

Comment: Added a solve for that too in the updated answer.

Comment: That's all. Thank you so much for your time @FUZIION : )

Comment: No problem :) Goodluck